# Why does len() work for generic slices but not the index operand?

Tags: go, generics, slice

I'm trying to write a function that works with generic slices. The `len` function understands that `T` is a slice but the index operator and the `make` function doesn't seem to work.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Numbers []int

type Strings []string

func PrintCoords[T Numbers | Strings](values T) {
    // It understands that it's a slice here and I can use len()
    for i := 0; i < len(values); i++ {
        fmt.Println(values[i]) // ERROR: invalid operation: cannot index values (variable of type T constrained by Numbers|Strings)
    }

        // I'm also not able to make a new slice of the same type?
    newValues := make(T, 0)
    newValues = append(newValues, values[0])
}
```

How can I make this simple example compile?

I've tried several variations of this but I can't make this function work with generics

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/QoYzSRI8eAR